# SQL Server 2012 fails to save nvarchar(MAX) > 42531 characters

Tags: sql-server

I have a nvarchar(MAX) field in my table called [Body]. I am trying to set that field to a (fairly) long string. I have discovered that if my string is > 42531 chars, the update statement runs, other fields are updated, but the [Body] field is set to an empty string. If I remove 1 char, from anywhere in the string, the [Body] field will contain the text I set. Nor the character I add / remove nor it's position have any effect on this, it's not a weird char or escaping problem.

```
DECLARE @p1 nvarchar(MAX)
SET @p1 = 'a string longer 
than 42531 chars...
with line breaks etc'
UPDATE [dbo].[MyTable] SET [Body] = @p1, CreatedOn = GETDATE() WHERE Id = 15597
```

How can this be?! It's very clear that nvarchar(MAX) can store up to 2GB of data, I'm not getting anywhere near that.

Comment: Is your code exactly as written with a single very long string literal or are you using string concatenation when defining the string?

Comment: Did you run a trace and see what is actually being sent? What happens if you skip the variable and build that string as part of the `UPDATE` command? Since it is `NVARCHAR`, why doesn't it have the `N'prefix'`?

Comment: Also would be curious to see if this works if you run the update in Management Studio on the same machine, connected with shared memory. Could be you are exceeding the limitations of packet size depending on what network protocols you are using...

Comment: Code is a single very long string, no concatenation happening. I'm trying this in Management Studio - I already pulled it out of my app. This is a development machine, I have everything running together. I tried with the `N` prefix in front (ie. `SET @p1=N'string...'` but no difference. I tried running it as part of the update command, no variable - no difference, same problem. I'll try running a trace in the morning...

Comment: I ran a trace on the update statement using the text as part of the statement (no variable). The entire string was present in the trace - there was no truncation happening between Management Studio and Profiler. Likewise if I used a variable - the entire string was being passed through.

Answer (score 0):

Uhhh, this is really weird. Maybe this is a Management Studio problem - as you can see in [this screenshot](http://screencast.com/t/Lr2JQjPDbfq), in SSMS the field appears empty for some records. However, I just discovered that I can place the cursor in the "empty" fields, press CTRL-C and copy the value out elsewhere - so the data is actually there, SSMS just isn't showing *any* of it! Even if I place the cursor in the field, the data doesn't visually appear, the field acts as if it's empty. However CTRL-C gets the data!

Maybe this is new to SSMS 2012 - I haven't seen this before.

I am aware of the SSMS ["Maximum number of characters displayed in each column"](http://screencast.com/t/gXg09XYRD) setting, which is set to 256. But I don't see how this can affect anything, since the other records (which have thousands of characters, but less than 42532 chars) do show data present, and if I place the cursor in those fields SSMS goes to the end of the text string, I can press F2 and move the cursor around within the whole string, not just 256 chars. However when there is > 42531 chars, I see nothing in the field...

Anyway, at least I now know the data is there!